# The Alaskan Dream

Tags: lateral-thinking

Scott is an expert outdoorsman, pursuing his dream by living in the remote Alaskan wilderness. Scott has everything he needs, and would prefer to remain a recluse, yet he will have to leave his home in four years. Why?

### Clues

#### Was something going to happen that would destroy Scott's home?

> No

#### Did Scott need to return to civilisation in order to buy food or clothing?

> No

#### Would Scott have been in danger if he ignored the four-year deadline?

> Yes

Comment: Doesn't the accepted answer contradict "Scott has everything he needs"? I read that as being "Scott has all supplies necessary to survive indefinitely" (except his eventual natural death, of course - he's not immortal), not just "all he needs today". Lacking the necessary replacement batteries for his pacemaker certainly suggests that he's lacking necessary survival supplies.

Comment: @TimS. yes and no. You can have a replacement, but actually replacing it requires [help](http://heartdisease.about.com/od/pacemakersdefibrillators/f/My-Battery-Is-Low-So-Why-Does-My-Whole-Pacemaker-Need-To-Be-Replaced.htm). (Big spoilers in the link. Little spoilers in next sentence.) No one has yet performed this on themselves, so it's not really a question of supplies.

Comment: What do you mean by "*leave his home*"? I wouldn't expect someone who's pursuing their dream of being an outdoorsman to spend all their time between four walls...

Comment: @Dacio but if he needs someone to re-install his pacemaker, he doesn't have everything he needs.

Comment: @EnvisionAndDevelop that's part of my point. He may have every*thing*, but he doesn't have *everyone* he needs. (foreveralone.jpg)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Scott has a pacemaker.
>  It runs on batteries.

Comment: How did you get that so quickly?

Comment: I don't know.  It was the first thing that came to my mind.

Comment: @BetaDecay Couldn't this be replaced by other medical procedures that occur on a time frame? "His heart was replaced six years ago and needs to be checked every ten years", etc. I'd say puzzles like this are better when there's *an* answer, not "What's the answer I'm thinking of?"

Comment: @Geobits Okay, I'll keep that in mind

Comment: How did I think of it?  I think it was your user name.  It made me think of smoke detectors that work with radioactive material.  And they need battery replacement.

Answer (score 11):

> The man who violently killed Scott's wife and attempted to kill Scott is currently incarcerated in a Baltimore correctional facility.
>  In four years, Scott will need to leave Alaska to testify at this man's parole hearing, lest the man be released and come after him.

Comment: Very very specific, but I suppose that's what lateral thinking is about afterall.

Answer (score 2):

He's an athlete in the Winter Olympics? I can't see that as dangerous, though.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to edit this answer to explain how you reached this conclusion given the information in the question?

Comment: @Emrakul - I used the combination of Alaska (cold) + 4 years + outdoorsman (athlete) and guessed.